# Upgrade Ubuntu linux-virtual on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu 10.10 EBS boot server on EC2.  There are new updates available for it:

- linux-image-virtual
- linux-virtual

Is it even ok to upgrade those packages on an EC2 server?

When I do try to upgrade them I get:

> The following packages have been kept back:
>   linux-image-virtual linux-virtual

Should I do a dist-upgrade or something to force it?  Will my instance be able to be rebooted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

or if it doesn't work

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Those packages won't upgrade with normal update. Your instance is going to be bootable if there is no other problem preventing it from that.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked and the server came back up after a reboot.